# Ansible regexp for netplan config dhcp4

Tags: ansible, netplan

I'm trying to edit the `01-netcfg.yml` file with Ansible. Below is the file:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
    enp12s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.1/24
    enp8s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.16.1/24
```

I'm trying to change the `dhcp4` value from `no` to `yes` under `enp0s31f6` only.

```yaml
- lineinfile:
        path: /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
        regexp: '      dhcp4: no'
        line: '      dhcp4: yes'
        insertbefore: '      nameservers:'
        firstmatch: True
        state: present
```

When I run the above code, it is modifying the `dhcp4` under `enp0s31f6` and also the `dhcp4` under `enp12s0`. I tried insertafter as well, but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: ***"Change the dhcp4 value from no to yes under enp0s31f6 only."***

---

Given the file for testing

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
    enp12s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.1/24
    enp8s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.16.1/24
```

---

A: Do not use the module *lineinfile* (1) in this use_case. The module *replace* (2) might be a better option. The best option is to fetch, update, and copy the file (3).

1. **lineinfile**

Generally, the module [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) is not able to update any neplane interface's parameter. In the particular case of the given file, the task below does the job

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml
        regexp: '^(\s+)dhcp4:\s+.*$'
        backrefs: true
        line: '\1dhcp4: yes'
        firstmatch: true
```

Running the play with the options *--check --diff* gives

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] *****************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml (content)
+++ after: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml (content)
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
   renderer: NetworkManager
   ethernets:
     enp0s31f6:
-      dhcp4: no
+      dhcp4: yes
       nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
     enp0s31f6:
```

This works because the interface `enp0s31f6` is first in the `ethernets` keys.

---

Notes:

- Set `backrefs: true`. Put the leading whitespace into the group `\1`
- Set `firstmatch: true`. The default *false* would match the last `dhcp4` in the interface `enp9s0`. Quoting from [*regexp*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp): *"Only the last line found will be replaced."*

---

This doesn't work if the interface `enp0s31f6` is not the first in the dictionary `ethernets`. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth01:
      dhcp4: no
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

The task below, even with the option `insertafter: enp0s31f6`

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml
        regexp: '^(\s+)dhcp4:\s+.*$'
        backrefs: true
        line: '\1dhcp4: yes'
        insertafter: enp0s31f6
        firstmatch: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] *****************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml (content)
+++ after: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml (content)
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
   renderer: NetworkManager
   ethernets:
     eth01:
-      dhcp4: no
+      dhcp4: yes
       nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
     enp0s31f6:
```

because `insertafter` doesn't work if `regexp` is matched. Quoting from [*regexp*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp):

> If the regular expression is not matched, the line will be added to the file in keeping with `insertbefore` or `insertafter` settings.

If you remove the option `regexp` the option `backrefs` can't work, and the regexp group `\1` can't be used in `line`. Then, the task below

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml
        line: '      dhcp4: yes'
        insertafter: enp0s31f6
        firstmatch: true
```

doesn't replace the existing parameter `dhcp4: no`. Instead, a new one will be added

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] *****************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml (content)
+++ after: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml (content)
@@ -7,6 +7,7 @@
       nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
     enp0s31f6:
+      dhcp4: yes
       dhcp4: no
       nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

---

2. **replace**

The module [*replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#ansible-builtin-replace-module-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) seems to be a better option. The task below

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml
        after: enp0s31f6
        before: enp12s0
        regexp: 'dhcp4:\s+.*\n'
        replace: 'dhcp4: yes\n'
```

does the job

```yaml
TASK [replace] ********************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml
+++ after: /tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
   renderer: NetworkManager
   ethernets:
     enp0s31f6:
-      dhcp4: no
+      dhcp4: yes
       nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
     enp12s0:
```

The problem is that you have to provide the option `before: enp12s0`. There might be another interface or none at all.

<TBD: get the value of *before*>

---

3. **Solution**

Use the module [*fetch*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#ansible-builtin-fetch-module-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) to fetch the file(s) and the filter [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) to update the configuration. Then, you can [*synchronize*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#ansible-posix-synchronize-module-a-wrapper-around-rsync-to-make-common-tasks-in-your-playbooks-quick-and-easy) the file(s) with the remote host(s). This procedure provides a robust, structured, and easily extensible framework for updating multiple netplan configuration files on multiple remote hosts in parallel.

Declare the path to netplan

```yaml
  netplan_dir: /tmp/netplan
```

and the dictionary with the updates

```yaml
  netplan_update:
    01-netcfg.yml:
      network:
        ethernets:
          enp0s31f6:
            dhcp4: yes
```

Running on the localhost for testing, fetch the file(s)

```yaml
    - fetch:
        dest: /tmp/fetch
        src: "{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_update.keys()|list }}"
```

Take a look at the fetched file(s)

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/fetch/
/tmp/fetch/
└── localhost
    └── tmp
        └── netplan
            └── 01-netcfg.yml

3 directories, 1 file
```

Read the configuration into the dictionary *netplan_orig*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        netplan_orig: "{{ netplan_orig|d({})|combine({item: conf}) }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_update.keys()|list }}"
      vars:
        file: "/tmp/fetch/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
        conf: "{{ lookup('file', file)|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  netplan_orig:
    01-netcfg.yml:
      network:
        ethernets:
          enp0s31f6:
            dhcp4: false
            nameservers:
              addresses:
              - 8.8.8.8
              - 8.8.4.4
          enp12s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.1/24
            dhcp4: false
          enp8s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.1.1/24
            dhcp4: false
          enp9s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.16.1/24
            dhcp4: false
        renderer: NetworkManager
        version: 2
```

Update the configuration. Declare the combination of the dictionaries

```yaml
  netplan_conf: "{{ netplan_orig|
                    combine(netplan_update, recursive=true) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  netplan_conf:
    01-netcfg.yml:
      network:
        ethernets:
          enp0s31f6:
            dhcp4: true
            nameservers:
              addresses:
              - 8.8.8.8
              - 8.8.4.4
          enp12s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.1/24
            dhcp4: false
          enp8s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.1.1/24
            dhcp4: false
          enp9s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.16.1/24
            dhcp4: false
        renderer: NetworkManager
        version: 2
```

Update the fetched files

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/fetch/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item.key }}"
        content: "{{ item.value|to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_conf|dict2items }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Take a look at the content of the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/fetch/localhost/tmp/netplan/01-netcfg.yml 
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
    enp12s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.1/24
      dhcp4: false
    enp8s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.1/24
      dhcp4: false
    enp9s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.16.1/24
      dhcp4: false
  renderer: NetworkManager
  version: 2
```

Synchronize the file(s)

```yaml
    - synchronize:
        src: "/tmp/fetch/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_update.keys()|list }}"
      # notify: netplan apply
```

Uncomment the *notify* directive to apply the configuration and create the handler

```yaml
  handlers:

    - name: netplan apply
      command: netplan apply
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    netplan_dir: /tmp/netplan

    netplan_update:
      01-netcfg.yml:
        network:
          ethernets:
            enp0s31f6:
              dhcp4: yes

    netplan_conf: "{{ netplan_orig|
                      combine(netplan_update, recursive=true) }}"

  tasks:

    - fetch:
        dest: /tmp/fetch
        src: "{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_update.keys()|list }}"
      tags: netplan_fetch

    - set_fact:
        netplan_orig: "{{ netplan_orig|d({})|combine({item: conf}) }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_update.keys()|list }}"
      vars:
        file: "/tmp/fetch/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
        conf: "{{ lookup('file', file)|from_yaml }}"
      tags: [netplan_read, netplan_update]
    - debug:
        var: netplan_orig
      tags: netplan_read
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
    - debug:
        var: netplan_conf
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
      tags: netplan_read

    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/fetch/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item.key }}"
        content: "{{ item.value|to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_conf|dict2items }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      tags: netplan_update

    - synchronize:
        src: "/tmp/fetch/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ netplan_dir }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ netplan_update.keys()|list }}"
      # notify: netplan apply
      tags: netplan_synchronize

  handlers:

    - name: netplan apply
      command: netplan apply
```

Comment: thank you @vladimir. it worked with `backrefs`